# Not able to ping onpremise ovpn client from azure opvn server but working the other way around

Tags: azure-vpn

I have an azure virtual network. That has a OpenVPN Access Server Azure Appliance, with a ip x.x.x.4 and vpn ip a.b.c.1 . Onpremise there is a OVPN client with ip x.y.z.7 and vpn ip a.b.c.4. I am able to ping x.x.x.4 from the onprem client, but from the openvpn appliance am not able to ping the onprem client. I am new to networking, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ovpn server webui page changed VPN settings->Routing->yes, using NAT to Yes,use Routing

https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/reach-openvpn-clients-directly-from-a-private-network/